# Dual N-channel MOSFET conducts with a single gate

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, digital-logic

I have several of these dual N-channel MOSFETs set up to control various 24 VDC devices (solenoids, lights, air valves, etc.), two of which you can see in the image below.

The ICs are logic-level and the gates are driven with 3.3 V from an MCU (RUN_LIGHT, OCTO_THUMP, MARK_SITE_AIR, and EXIT_AIR).

I have no problem triggering the MOSFET and measuring 24 V across the headers (J18, J10, J12, J15), but triggering G1 not only connects D1 and S1, but also connects D2 and S2. Vice versa works by triggering G2. If I measure voltage across J18, I also see it across J15, etc.

Using this same circuit configuration with single-channel MOSFETs, like the IRLZ44N, works like a charm.

I checked to make sure I only had 3.3 V at the intended gate, and I did, so no shorts.

Apologies if I'm missing something fundamental here.

edit: Datasheet https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/916/BUK9K5R6-30E-1319949.pdf

edit 2: Footprint [image]

[image]

Comment: A link to the data sheet is missing. Also, where did you buy them from? Show your footprint for the device.

Comment: Datasheet added. These were purchased from Mouser. Footprint is in the datasheet, or are you wanting to see it on my board?

Comment: Show `your` footprint for the device.

Comment: Looks like some connection issue then. Or your part is not what it claims to be (gates internally connected?). Check continuity between the supposed gate pins just in case to rule it out. On PCB and off PCB.

Comment: I think Andy nailed it. It looks like the footprint I used has a central pad that must be shorting D1 and D2. (footprint added)

Comment: FWIW, KiCAD footprints should be taken with a grain of salt. As a rule, I'll put them on a board, then print a 1:1 output, then physically place the components on each to make sure they will fit.  Usually, one or more footprints need adjusting.